# How to explain inline PTX Internal Compiler Error of CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, ptx

I want to measure the cache behavior of gpu global memory and below is the micro-benchmark that i design. What i want to do is to load from global memory address r_add0 and store it into shared memory s_tvalue[0]. For some reason, i need to replace the loading instruction from global memory with inline PTX code.

```
i = *r_addr0;
//asm("ldu.global.f64.cs %1, [%2];":"=l"(i):"l"(r_addr0));
s_tvalue[0] = i;
```

**However, when i compile it with nvcc, it complaint with compile error**

```
error: Internal Compiler Error (codegen): "asm operand index requested is larger than the number of asm operands provided!"
```

**Does anybody knows the reason to my codes.**

Complete codes see below:

```
__global__ void global_latency (long long * my_array, 
                                long long array_length, int position, 
                                long long *d_time) 
{

    unsigned int start_time, end_time;

    __shared__ long long s_tvalue[2];//2: number of threads per block

    int k;
    long long i, j;
    for(k=0; k<2; k++)
        s_tvalue[k] = 0L;
    long long addr0,addr1;

    addr0=(long long)my_array;

    addr1 = ( addr0 ^ (1 << position));

    long long *r_addr0, *r_addr1;
    r_addr0 = (long long *)addr0;
    r_addr1 = (long long *)addr1;

    start_time = clock();
    //i = *r_addr0;
    asm("ldu.global.f64.cs %1, [%2];":"=l"(i):"l"(r_addr0));

    s_tvalue[0] = i;
    //j = *r_addr1;
    asm("ld.global.f64.cs %3, [%4];" : "=l"(j):"l"(r_addr1));
    s_tvalue[1] = j;


    end_time = clock();

    d_time[0] = end_time-start_time;
    d_time[1] = s_tvalue[0];
    printf("[%p]=%lld\n",addr0,d_time[1]);
    d_time[2] = s_tvalue[1];
    printf("[%p]=%lld\n",addr1,d_time[2]);  
}
```

Comment: In my experience, tokens are zero based.  Since you only have 2 parameters, that would be %0 and %1.  You are using %2, which "is larger than the number of asm operands provided."  I'm also not clear on what you think the asm is going to do.  It looks like it's trying to assign a value to i ("=l")?

Comment: See also cross-post [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/940109/cuda-programming-and-performance/cuda-inline-ptx-internal-compiler-error/)

Comment: Thank you both, @DavidWohlferd and njuffa, you point out the reason.

Comment: It's inappropriate on SO to put [solved] in the question title.  A question is "solved" on SO when there is an answer that is provided that has been upvoted or accepted.  Would someone like to provide an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, tokens are zero based. Since you only have 2 parameters, that would be %0 and %1. You are using %2, which "is larger than the number of asm operands provided."